# Drupal 7 field sharing between translations of a node

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

Consider I have a content type which I want to be translated into 5 languages. Also consider that my content type has 10 fields of which 7 of them are numbers and 3 of them are text.

There is no need for that 7 fields to be translated to each language,
but when I translate each content I should spend a lot of time on filling same values for each language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing the 7 fields in a 1st content type and the 3 remaining fields in a 2nd content type. And then use the [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module to connect them to each other? That way you'd only have to "translate" the content type with the 3 fields.

A variation of this could be using entities, whereas you'd then use the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module instead. And probably also the [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module, for which quite some [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1280632) is available to get you started.

[Drupal 7's new multilingual systems compilation](http://hojtsy.hu/multilingual-drupal7) contains an interesting set of posts about multilanguage websites ...

PS: You may also want to look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17466/ for a lot of extra info/details about both variations of translations.